# Receive messages with a protocol?

Tags: ios, protocols

I'm currently learning Obj-C and more specifically - protocols. I will need to make up a scenario here for my question to make sense.

First example (with a delegate).

1. I'm a UIView subclass which requests information from it's controller to be displayed (or rather how the information should be displayed). I declare a protocol and make a delegate reference object (or whatever it's called):

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, weak) id <protocolName> dataSource;
   ```
2. My controller conforms to this protocol and implements the required method.
3. View sends messages to the Controller, and the Controller answers and everything is fine.

This as far as I know is **delegation** through protocols and I believe I understand it.

**But let's consider another scenario.**

1. I'm a class which is the brain for a simple level-based game. I say when to show the menu or when to start playing a game level. **But I need to know when a level is completed.**

Which means this class needs to be ready to receive messages from anyone that implements the protocol, for example from another class which is responsible for the current level. **Now this is what I don't understand**. How the protocol should look like and where/how to implement it?

Let me know if my question still doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate is a one-to-on relationship method for sending message between entities.
If you want to receive the same message from different class, you can use `NSNotification` that is a one-to-many relationship.

Look at the `NSNotificationCenter` class, especially `postNotification` method (for sending messages) and `addObserver` method (used when received a notification)

EDIT :
Here's an example code for delegation.

Let's take your game level-based example. You have a `LevelManager` class and `FirstLevel` class. If you want the `LevelManager` to be notice when the `FirstLevel` ended, you have to declare a protocol in your `FirstLevel` class

```
// FirstLevel.h
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)levelDidEnd;
@end

@interface FirstLevel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SomeProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

Then somewhere in your FirstLevel.m, call your protocol method when the level ended

```
// FirstLevel.m
- (void)playGame {
    if ([player isDead]) {
        [delegate levelDidEnd];
    }
}
```

The next step is to implement your protocol to your LevelManager :

```
// LevelManager.h
@interface LevelManager : NSObject <SomeProtocol>
@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstLevel *firstLevel;
@end
```

And then, set your `firstLevel.delegate` and implement your protocol method

```
// LevelManager.h
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    firstLevel.delegate = self;
}

- (void) didLevelEnd {
    // do actions here like showing the menu
}
```

Comment: By messages I meant methods, not notifications. Or I didn't understand your answer?

Comment: Mhh maybe i'm the one who didn't understand here. Were you asking for an example code of delegation ?

Answer (score 0):

You still can go with delegation:

Let the level be a object with an delegate of type `id<LevelDelegate>`

```
@protocol LevelDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)completedLevel:(Level *)level;
@end
```

The BrainController conforms to `LevelDelegate` and creates all levels. for each level it set itself as delegate.

If a level recognizes it has finished, it calls `[self.delegate completedLevel:self];`.

The BrainController gets informed and does what ever is necessary.